# Find value from array into array in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I unable to make filter in query to get perticular partner data.

I have this document in Collection (Couchbase). I need filter to set property id is HTL470.1 and partner id is RDK400 and get result from key rd_property_operations;

I have Couchbase query but it is not work properly

Query :

```
SELECT channelSwitch.business_setting,
        rdpo.customer_partner_id,
        rdpo.property_id,
        rdpo.property_code,
        rdpo.property_name,
        rdpo.country,
        rdpo.status,
        rdpo.action,
        rdpo.is_suspended_by_property,
        rdpo.is_suspended_by_partner,
        rdpo.updated_date as last_update,        
        rdpo.partner_setup_status
        from `bucketName`.`scopeName`.`ChannelSwitch` channelSwitch
        UNNEST business_setting.rd_property_operations rdpo        
        WHERE rdpo.status=3
        AND rdpo.action=3
        AND rdpo.property_code = 'HTL470.1'
        AND channelSwitch.business_setting
        AND rdpo.customer_partner_id  = 'RDK400'
```

Here is document

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [action] => 3
            [business_setting] => Array
                (
                    [rd_property_operations] => Array
                        (
                            

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [action] => 3
                                    [ch_manager] => 
                                    [country] => New Zealand
                                    [created_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [created_date] => 2021-07-27 05:50:17
                                    [customer_id] => 131
                                    [customer_partner_id] => RDK131
                                    [id] => 630
                                    [is_submitted_by_property] => 1
                                    [is_suspended_by_partner] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_property] => 0
                                    [message] => 
                                    [partner_setup_status] => 1
                                    [property_code] => HTL503.2
                                    [property_id] => 1678
                                    [property_name] => New Zealand Property
                                    [status] => 3
                                    [updated_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [updated_date] => 2022-10-21 04:50:49
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [action] => 3
                                    [ch_manager] => 
                                    [country] => New Zealand
                                    [created_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [created_date] => 2021-07-10 07:43:26
                                    [customer_id] => 132
                                    [customer_partner_id] => RDK132
                                    [id] => 570
                                    [is_submitted_by_property] => 1
                                    [is_suspended_by_partner] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_property] => 0
                                    [message] => 
                                    [partner_setup_status] => 1
                                    [property_code] => HTL503.2
                                    [property_id] => 1678
                                    [property_name] => New Zealand Property
                                    [status] => 3
                                    [updated_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [updated_date] => 2022-10-21 04:50:50
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [action] => 3
                                    [ch_manager] => 
                                    [country] => New Zealand
                                    [created_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [created_date] => 2021-05-28 07:36:14
                                    [customer_id] => 133
                                    [customer_partner_id] => RDK133
                                    [id] => 308
                                    [is_submitted_by_property] => 1
                                    [is_suspended_by_partner] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_property] => 0
                                    [message] => 
                                    [partner_setup_status] => 1
                                    [property_code] => HTL503.2
                                    [property_id] => 1678
                                    [property_name] => New Zealand Property
                                    [status] => 3
                                    [updated_by] => RDK133
                                    [updated_date] => 2022-10-18 11:26:22
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [action] => 3
                                    [ch_manager] => 
                                    [country] => New Zealand
                                    [created_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [created_date] => 2021-05-12 06:56:55
                                    [customer_id] => 134
                                    [customer_partner_id] => RDK134
                                    [id] => 185
                                    [is_submitted_by_property] => 1
                                    [is_suspended_by_partner] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_property] => 0
                                    [message] => 
                                    [partner_setup_status] => 1
                                    [property_code] => HTL503.2
                                    [property_id] => 1678
                                    [property_name] => #14--> "pune' @ Hn % 6^7__ [brentwood Hotel]~~` \ & |
                                    [status] => 3
                                    [updated_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [updated_date] => 2022-10-21 04:50:50
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [action] => 4
                                    [ch_manager] => 
                                    [country] => New Zealand
                                    [created_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [created_date] => 2021-06-01 10:53:48
                                    [customer_id] => 135
                                    [customer_partner_id] => RDK0
                                    [id] => 324
                                    [is_submitted_by_property] => 1
                                    [is_suspended_by_partner] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_property] => 0
                                    [message] => 
                                    [partner_setup_status] => 1
                                    [property_code] => HTL503.2
                                    [property_id] => 1678
                                    [property_name] => New Zealand Property
                                    [status] => 4
                                    [updated_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [updated_date] => 2021-06-01 10:53:48
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [action] => 3
                                    [ch_manager] => 
                                    [country] => New Zealand
                                    [created_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [created_date] => 2021-07-15 05:35:16
                                    [customer_id] => 188
                                    [customer_partner_id] => RDK188
                                    [id] => 612
                                    [is_submitted_by_property] => 1
                                    [is_suspended_by_partner] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_property] => 0
                                    [message] => 
                                    [partner_setup_status] => 1
                                    [property_code] => HTL503.2
                                    [property_id] => 1678
                                    [property_name] => New Zealand Property
                                    [status] => 3
                                    [updated_by] => RDK188
                                    [updated_date] => 2022-09-14 10:52:01
                                )

                            [7] => Array
                                (
                                    [action] => 3
                                    [ch_manager] => 
                                    [country] => New Zealand
                                    [created_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [created_date] => 2021-08-15 04:27:05
                                    [customer_id] => 307
                                    [customer_partner_id] => RDK307
                                    [id] => 687
                                    [is_submitted_by_property] => 1
                                    [is_suspended_by_partner] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_property] => 0
                                    [message] => 
                                    [partner_setup_status] => 1
                                    [property_code] => HTL503.2
                                    [property_id] => 1678
                                    [property_name] => New Zealand Property
                                    [status] => 3
                                    [updated_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [updated_date] => 2022-10-21 04:50:53
                                )

                            [8] => Array
                                (
                                    [action] => 1
                                    [ch_manager] => 
                                    [country] => New Zealand
                                    [created_by] => RDK391
                                    [created_date] => 2022-03-15 09:17:32
                                    [customer_id] => 391
                                    [customer_partner_id] => RDK391
                                    [id] => 937
                                    [is_submitted_by_property] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_partner] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_property] => 0
                                    [message] => 
                                    [partner_setup_status] => 1
                                    [property_code] => HTL503.2
                                    [property_id] => 1678
                                    [property_name] => New Zealand Property
                                    [status] => 1
                                    [updated_by] => RDK391
                                    [updated_date] => 2022-07-11 06:24:16
                                )

                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                    [action] => 3
                                    [ch_manager] => 
                                    [country] => New Zealand
                                    [created_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [created_date] => 2022-03-09 11:36:09
                                    [customer_id] => 394
                                    [customer_partner_id] => RDK394
                                    [id] => 914
                                    [is_submitted_by_property] => 1
                                    [is_suspended_by_partner] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_property] => 0
                                    [message] => 
                                    [partner_setup_status] => 1
                                    [property_code] => HTL503.2
                                    [property_id] => 1678
                                    [property_name] => New Zealand Property
                                    [status] => 3
                                    [updated_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [updated_date] => 2022-12-19 11:05:23
                                )

                            [10] => Array
                                (
                                    [action] => 3
                                    [ch_manager] => 
                                    [country] => New Zealand
                                    [created_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [created_date] => 2022-03-11 11:43:13
                                    [customer_id] => 399
                                    [customer_partner_id] => RDK399
                                    [id] => 931
                                    [is_submitted_by_property] => 1
                                    [is_suspended_by_partner] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_property] => 0
                                    [message] => 
                                    [partner_setup_status] => 1
                                    [property_code] => HTL503.2
                                    [property_id] => 1678
                                    [property_name] => New Zealand Property
                                    [status] => 3
                                    [updated_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [updated_date] => 2022-10-21 04:50:56
                                )

                            [11] => Array
                                (
                                    [action] => 3
                                    [ch_manager] => 
                                    [country] => New Zealand
                                    [created_by] => RDK400
                                    [created_date] => 2022-04-30 09:45:16
                                    [customer_id] => 400
                                    [customer_partner_id] => RDK400
                                    [id] => 1051
                                    [is_submitted_by_property] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_partner] => 0
                                    [is_suspended_by_property] => 0
                                    [message] => 
                                    [partner_setup_status] => 1
                                    [property_code] => HTL503.2
                                    [property_id] => 1678
                                    [property_name] => New Zealand Property
                                    [status] => 3
                                    [updated_by] => HTL503.2
                                    [updated_date] => 2022-10-21 04:50:57
                                )

                          

                          

                        )

                  
                    [taxes_manage_busi_setting] => Array
                        (
                            [created_by] => HTL503.2
                            [created_date] => 2021-05-12 07:05:24
                            [prop_code] => HTL503.2
                            [prop_id] => 1678
                            [tax_room_after_rate] => Add Charge
                            [tax_room_after_update] => 2
                            [tax_room_before_rate] => Add Charge
                            [tax_room_before_update] => 2
                            [tax_room_meet_after_rate] => No Effect
                            [tax_room_meet_after_update] => 
                            [tax_room_meet_before_rate] => No Effect
                            [tax_room_meet_before_update] => 
                            [taxes_manage_id] => 6
                            [updated_by] => HTL503.2
                            [updated_date] => 2023-03-31 11:16:57
                        )

                )

            [country] => New Zealand
            [customer_partner_id] => RDK400
            [is_suspended_by_partner] => 0
            [is_suspended_by_property] => 0
            [last_update] => 2022-10-21 04:50:57
            [partner_setup_status] => 1
            [property_code] => HTL503.2
            [property_id] => 1678
            [property_name] => New Zealand Property
            [status] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: It's a little hard to see the field nestings, could you update the example to be in JSON format?

Comment: Is the top-level of the document an array as well as `business_setting` and `rd_property_operations`? I "think" you'll need to unnest all of the array levels in order to be able to access the `property_code`.  Or are you trying to filter off of the same fields that exist just at the `business_setting` level?